# error when fetching data from sqlite db using Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, sqlite

I connected to sqlite db and tried to fetch data from a table .

but its showing some error ,

Fatal error: Call to a member function lastErrorCode() on a non-object in D:\xampp\htdocs\e-hadith\system\database\drivers\sqlite3\sqlite3_driver.php on line 300
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Error

Message: Call to a member function lastErrorCode() on a non-object

Filename: sqlite3/sqlite3_driver.php

Line Number: 300

Backtrace:

below is my code

```html
{
         $this->db->select("*");
         $q=$this->db->get("chapter");
         $r=$q->result();
         echo "<pre>";print_r($r);exit;


        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }
```

```html
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => '',
    'username' => '',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'sqlite:'.APPPATH.'/Database/data.db',
    'dbdriver' => 'sqlite3',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => FALSE,
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

Can any one suggest me ?

[image]

Comment: have you loaded the database ?

Comment: I am using db browser for sqlite @ManiKandan Kandan

Comment: i guess you need to give hostname, username and password for database

Answer (score 0):

It looks there is some error in database configuration.

Possible issues

1. Database Configuration Issue.

`'database' => 'sqlite:'.APPPATH.'/Database/data.db'`, this is wrong.

In CodeIgniter `APPPATH` refers to the `application` directory.

As per your screenshot your sqlite database is outside of the `application` directory.

1. Move the `data.db` file inside `application/database`.
2. Update the config `'database' => APPPATH.'/database/data.db'`
3. Edit `application/config/autoload.php` and load database library.

Hope this will resolve your issue.

Comment: put 1 exit after echo $this->db->last_query();

Comment: I have updated the answer with another query way. I can guess the table named `chapter` doesn't exist in the database or you have connected to wrong database.

Comment: What is the database configuration?

Comment: I have given code of database.php,can you plz check?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141980/discussion-between-bikram-pahi-and-sradha).

Answer (score 0):

First thing try to check your php.ini and uncomment this

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
extension=php_sqlite3.dll
```

and try this

```
// in the dsn put sqlite:your/path/to/Database
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => 'sqlite:application/Database/data.db',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => '',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => '',
    'dbdriver' => 'pdo',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```